# Error configuring multiple java keystores using dks KeyStore type

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, keytool

I have a Java/tomcat base application that uses the standard JDK SSL API.
To simplify the keystore management I would like to have 2 trust keystore files that are merged. One from the Oracle JDK ($JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts) and one specific to my company.
In Java 8 it is possible to use multiple keystores by using a [DKS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyStore) keystore type.

I've configured ssl-keystore-test.dks with the following content:

```
domain app1 {
     keystore app1-truststore
         keystoreType="JKS"
         keystoreURI="file:///opt/myapp/testkeystore.jks";

     keystore system-truststore
         keystoreURI="${java.home}/lib/security/cacerts";

 };
```

When I try to list the certificates from the keystore I receive the following error:

```
# /opt/jdk1.8/jre/bin/keytool -list -keystore ssl-keystore-test.dks -storetype dks -storepass changeit
keytool error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This keystore must be loaded using a DomainLoadStoreParameter
```

What is the proper way to merge at runtime 2 keystores if you do not have access to change the application?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the DKS keystore type can only be use programmatically.  I think you'll have to manually merge the two keystores.  Look at the `keytool -importkeystore` command, which copies keys from one keystore to another.

Comment: I had the same feeling like you, but I when I found the script from the following URL I realized it is possible: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~michaelm/7113349/jdk8/webrev.2/jdk/test/sun/security/tools/keytool/AltProviderPath.sh.html

Comment: Through, I might change the startup script to (re)generate a merged keystore if any of the dependent ones are newer than the generated one.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici Interesting example.  But, the example uses a custom provider `org.test.dummy.DummyProvider` and I thought the OP said he couldn't change the application.

Comment: I think that provider is a test class for the purpose of Unit Testing.